# Is the ideal $\{2m + (1 + \sqrt{-6})n:m, n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Is the ideal $\{2m + (1 + \sqrt{-6})n:m, n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$?

I have an exercise that asks just that. As a hint it says to prove that this ideal contains $1$, hinting that the authors consider it being principal correct answer. But it doesn't look to me like it's principal at all. So is it or is it not? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written isn't an ideal. What you presumably **meant** to write is
$$I=(2,1+\sqrt{-6})=\{2\alpha+(1+\sqrt{-6})\beta:\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]\}$$

Now, how to prove that $I$ is principal? I'll give a further hint there. Because $1+\sqrt{-6}\in I$ and $1-\sqrt{-6}\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$,  we have (by the definition of ideal)
$$7=1^2-(-6)=(1+\sqrt{-6})(1-\sqrt{-6})\in I.$$
Now use that $2\in I$ also.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the difference between my ideal and $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-6})$, but in the exercise $m, n\in\mathbb{Z}$. It must be typo then.